# How do I save special characters from a textfield ('+<>$") into a database, then retrieve them with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a textarea created for a personal message, with a subject. It is passed to a Javascript/jQuery function, which passes it to a PHP file to store in the database. However, when special characters such as the ampersand, less than, greater than, apostrophe, plus sign, and quotations are used, it doesn't store correctly in my database. So without saying, when I retrieve the data, the data is not displayed properly.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <input id="pmsubject" placeholder="Subject"><br />
 <textarea id="pmtext" placeholder="Send a private message"></textarea>
 <button id="pmBtn" onclick="postPm(pmsubject,pmtext)">Send</button>
```

Here is the Javascript/jQuery (partial):

```
function postPm(subject,textarea){
    var data = $("#textarea").val();
    var data2 = $("#subject").val();
```

I do some error checking and handling then send my information with AJAX:

```
type: "POST",
url: "pm_system.php",
data:"data="+data+"&data2="+data2,
```

So far so good right? Here is the pm_system.php portion where I store the code:

```
$data = htmlentities($_POST['data']);
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_con, $data);
$data2 = htmlentities($_POST['data2']);
$data2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_con, $data2);

$sql = "INSERT INTO pm(subject, message) 
        VALUES('$data2','$data')";
$query = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql);
mysqli_close($db_con);
```

So if I write a message that says, I'm a big fan of cats + dogs & "sometimes" birds. My output would be:

```
I\'m a big fan of cats   dogs
```

It always puts slashes in front of quotations and apostrophes, always replaces + sign with a space, and nothing follows after an ampersand sign. I've tried replacing the characters like this in Javascript:

```
data = data.replace(/\"/g, '&quot;'); //Just using one for example
```

But that doesn't work either. How do I save these characters from a textarea in a database, unaltered?

Comment: I haven't used PHP in ages but I'm fairly certain there's a feature in mysqli to fill in variables to the query without actually escaping them and then adding them to the string.

Comment: Yeah, that's called Prepared Statements. You can look into those... I believe there's an unescape() method or something along those lines.

Comment: @ChristianStewart You mean [prepared statements?](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I guess I do :) Just thought that might be a reasonable starting point for him to look at .

Comment: I don't know if it'll help, but if you pass data as an object of key-value pairs, jQuery will do the encoding for you: `data: {"data" : data, "data2" : data2 }`

Comment: It still will not do the + or & signs!

Answer (score 2):

I would guess, that the data you receive through your JavaScript function is already escaped. So when you enter `I'm a big fan of cats dog` you get `I\'m a big fan of cats dogs` in your PHP script. When you than use `mysqli_real_escape()` you are adding another escape character.

So you might want to replace the escape character before:

```
$data = stripslashes($_POST['data']);
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_con, $data);
$data2 = stripslashes($_POST['data2']);
$data2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_con, $data2);

$sql = "INSERT INTO pm(subject, message) 
        VALUES('$data2','$data')";
$query = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql);
mysqli_close($db_con);
```

I would not recommend to use `htmlentities()` but save the data "as is" into the database as otherwise things like full text searches don't work correctly.

The issue with the + sign is probably because you send the values as a query string `data:"data="+data+"&data2="+data2` and in a URL, a + sign is used for a space. To fix that, you should rather pass the data as an object:

```
type: "POST",
url: "pm_system.php",
data: { "data": data, "data2": data2 },
```

That should fix also most of the other problematic characters.

Comment: How would I pass this as an object?
`data:"action=new_pm&fuser="+fuser+"&tuser="+tuser+"&data="+data+"&data2="+data2,`

Comment: `stripslashes()` took care of the quotations...It's getting there!

Comment: Just as in my example above. An object in JavaScript looks like this: `{ "key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2" }` so for your query you should have something like this: `data: { "action": new_pm, "fuser": fuser, "tuser": tuser, "data": data, "data2": data2‌ }`. But you might want to rename your JS variables to something different than data, action etc. to not get confused with the jQuery AJAX optoins.

Comment: Thanks 2ndkauboy! I have all characters working except the ampersand and plus sign. It won't save anything in the database after the '&'! I've thought about doing this: `data = data.replace(/&/g, '[amp]');` In my JS, then this in PHP: `$data = str_replace("[amp]", "&", $_POST['data']);`

Comment: You might want to try `data = encodeURI(data)` in your JS function. That should solve those special characters. In case they are than double encoded in PHP, use the `$data = urldecode($data)` to decode it again.

Comment: 2ndkauboy - tried that and tried `data = data.encodeURIComponent('+').encodeURIComponent('&');` and I still can't get those two to show up!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `htmlentities()`. I've had some troubles with `htmlentities()` and outputting the data in the past. Using `htmlspecialchars()` solved it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).